# Signing in a user through django restframework (Android)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to django rest-framework, but I am able create basic apis . But I wanted to know how can I log in a user from Android.
Should I create a api view which takes post data (username,password) and then tries the login method and return if user is successfully logged in or not? 
How should I proceed ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

first, you should serialize your user class

```
class UserLoginSerializer(ModelSerializer):
token = CharField(read_only=True)
phone_number = IntegerField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = [
        # 'id',
        'phone_number',
        'password',
        'token'
    ]
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password': {
            'write_only': True
        }
    }

def validate(self, data):
    phone_number = data['phone_number']
    password = data['password']
    if not phone_number:
        raise ValidationError('Phone number is required to login.')
    user = User.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
    if not user:
        raise ValidationError('Your account does not exist.')
    elif not user.check_password(password):
        raise ValidationError('Incorrect password, please try again.')
    return data
```

then, you should create your login view class

```
class UserLoginAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserLoginSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all().filter(is_active=True)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        user = User.objects.all()
        try:
            user =
```

user.get(Q(phone_number__iexact=request.data['phone_number']))
            except:
                return Response({'error': 'user does not exist.'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
            if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            # serializer.save()
                return Response({'id': user.id}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

after doing this two thing you need to add your view class to a URL

```
url(r'^login/$', UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name='user-login')
```